# Copia entre strings dentro de listas Python

Tags: python, lista, python-2.7

A operação consiste em comparar duas listas de strings, detectar quais os itens e comuns e coloca-los numa determinada ordem numa nova lista.

O mais próximo que cheguei foi:

```
nova = []

lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

coluna = ['a', '1', '2', '4', 'b', '2', '4', '5', '6', 'c', '3', '3', '3', 'd', '3', '3', 'e', '1']
```

O objetivo é, a partir dos itens coincidentes, copiá-los até chegar ao próximo, copiar, e assim por diante, até formar uma lista como essa:

```
nova = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd','d', 'd', 'e', 'e']
```

Ou seja, a depender dos índices coincidentes entre duas listas, estes serão copiados até chegar ao próximo.

O mais próximo que cheguei da resposta foi usando um laço aninhado:

```
for item_lista in lista:

 for item_coluna in coluna:

   if(item_lista==item_coluna):
    
      nova.append(item_lista)

   else:
     nova.append(item_coluna)
```

Retorna-se uma lista, mas a errada do que eu pretendia:

```
nova=['a',
 '1',
 '2',
 '4',
 'b',
 '2',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 'c',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 'd',
 '3',
 '3',
 'e',
 '1',
 'a',
 '1',
 '2',
 '4',
 'b',
 '2',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 'c',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 'd',
 '3',
 '3',
 'e',
 '1',
 'a',
 '1',
 '2',
 '4',
 'b',
 '2',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 'c',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 'd',
 '3',
 '3',
 'e',
 '1',
 'a',
 '1',
 '2',
 '4',
 'b',
 '2',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 'c',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 'd',
 '3',
 '3',
 'e',
 '1',
 'a',
 '1',
 '2',
 '4',
 'b',
 '2',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 'c',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 'd',
 '3',
 '3',
 'e',
 '1']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use uma variável `l` para guardar o caractere a ser repetido e então itere pelos elementos da lista `coluna` e um a um, em `c` e verifique se estão contidos na lista `lista`:

- se sim o `c` estiver contido em `lista` atribua esse caractere a variável `l` e adicione a lista `nova`.
- se não adicione `l` a lista `nova`.

Exemplo:

```
nova = []
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
coluna = ['a', '1', '2', '4', 'b', '2', '4', '5', '6', 'c', '3', '3', '3', 'd', '3', '3', 'e', '1']

l= coluna[0]

for c in coluna:  
  nova.append(l := c if c in lista else l)

print(nova)
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/MisturarListas1#main.py)</sup>

Ou então aplique o mesmo raciocínio usando list comprehension:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
coluna = ['a', '1', '2', '4', 'b', '2', '4', '5', '6', 'c', '3', '3', '3', 'd', '3', '3', 'e', '1']

l=coluna[0]
nova = [l:= c if c in lista else l for c in coluna]

print(nova)
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repli.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/MisturarListas2#main.py)</sup>

Ambos os códigos resultam em:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e']
```

Answer (score 2):

Caso a `lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` não for mandatório

o código a seguir repete a letra encontrada até encontrar uma nova letra

```
nova = []
for x in coluna:

    if x.isnumeric():
        nova.append(letra)
    else:
        nova.append(x)
        letra = x
    
print(nova)
```

Caso for mandatório...

```
nova = []
letra = ''
for x in coluna:
    
        if x.isnumeric():
            if letra in lista:
                nova.append(letra)
        else:
            if x in lista:
                nova.append(x)
                letra = x
    
print(nova)
```

Comment: O caso mandatório resolveu minha situação! Muito obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 2):

De forma recursiva, talvez queira brincar um pouco mais:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

coluna = ['a', '1', '2', '4', 'b', '2', '4', '5', '6', 'c', '3', '3', '3', 'd', '3', '3', 'e', '1']

nova = []


def agrupar(pos):
    if coluna[pos] in lista:
        nova.append(coluna[pos])
        agrupar(pos + 1)
    else:
        nova.append(nova[-1])
        if pos + 1 < len(coluna):
            agrupar(pos + 1)


agrupar(0)
print(nova)
```